# Setting NotANumberSymbol to an empty string?

Tags: nsstring, cocoa-bindings, nan, foundation, nsnumberformatter

why NSNumberFormatter's method setNotANumberSymbol:(NSString *)string ignores the empty string as a parameter (@"")? It even ignores the string, if it contains only spaces and zeros (@" 0 0 0 ")?

Is there any way to bypass this functionality, and to tell to the number formatter that nothing is shown instead of NaN?

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the number object before setting the labels output using the  `nilSymbol` method:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
numberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
numberFormatter.nilSymbol = @"?"; //here you can set whatever you like

cell.yourLabel.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@", [numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:yourNSNumberObject]];
```

For me it works even with empty inputs for the number object.